# An elegant way to get the output of `normxcorr2` in a manner similar to 'conv2' - (removing the unwanted edges)

Tags: matlab, convolution, cross-correlation

Is there an **elegant** way in Matlab to get the output of `normxcorr2` cropped to the size of the image or cropped only to the part of the matrix that does not use zero padded edges in computation?

To understand what I mean, consider the `conv2` command. There is an optional parameter called `shape` that can be set to `same` or `valid`.

```
C = conv2(A,B,'same');
C = conv2(A,B,'valid');
```

For example:

```
size( conv2( rand(50,50) , rand(6,6), 'valid') )
```

ans =

```
45    45
```

---

```
size( conv2( rand(50,50) , rand(6,6), 'same') )
```

ans =

```
50    50
```

---

```
size( conv2( rand(50,50) , rand(6,6)) )
```

ans =

```
55    55
```

Currently I wrote my own function, that does something like this:

```
function I = normxcorr2e(template,im,shape)
    switch shape
        case 'same'
            I = normxcorr2(template,im);
            r = size(I,1)-size(im,1);
            c = size(I,2)-size(im,2);

            m1=floor(r/2);
            n1=floor(c/2);
            m2=ceil(r/2);
            n2=ceil(c/2);

            I(1:m2,:) = [];
            I(end-m1+1:end,:) = [];

            I(:,1:n2) = [];
            I(:,end-n1+1:end) = [];
        case 'full'
            %Do nothing
        case 'valid'
            %TODO - write this case...
        otherwise
            throw(Mexception('normxcorr2e:BadInput','shape %s is not recognized',shape));
    end

end
```

Do you have a better idea? The main criterion for a successful answer will be the **elegance** of the proposed solution.

**Edit(1)** First of all, thanks for all of your answers. All of them are good and upvoted by me. I still haven't decided which is the best. By the way, I am thinking recently about the case where the template is large compared to the image. In that case, it makes sense to speedup the computation by cropping the `image` argument before running `normxcorr2`.

Comment: Does correctness count as well? :)

Comment: @Jonas, yes :) Elegance is the main criterion, not the only

Comment: I tried to find a way that you could call your function by the same name and shadow the toolbox version, letting it act as an unseen wrapper. Unfortunately, invoking a shadowed function with [BUILTIN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/builtin.html) only works for *non-toolbox* built-in functions, so I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: @gnovice, it is a nice idea, but in practice it can cause havoc in deployed code :( I tried to override `disp` once and the behavior was very odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a variant that has a few extra features relative to the other answers:

- It allows you to omit the shape argument (default is `'full'`).
- It only calls [`normxcorr2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/normxcorr2.html) when `shape` is a valid string.
- It performs the indexing in one line using [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1). The sizes of the lead padding and desired center region is used to create index vectors of true and false values. The trailing padding doesn't need to be specified since a logical index that is shorter than the dimension it indexes will simply be padded with false values.

And here's the code:

```
function I = normxcorr2e(template, im, shape)

  if (nargin == 2) || strcmp(shape,'full')
      I = normxcorr2(template, im);
      return
  end

  switch shape
      case 'same'
          pad = floor(size(template)./2);
          center = size(im);
      case 'valid'
          pad = size(template) - 1;
          center = size(im) - pad;
      otherwise
          throw(Mexception('normxcorr2e:BadInput',...
              'SHAPE must be ''full'', ''same'', or ''valid''.'));
  end

  I = normxcorr2(template, im);
  I = I([false(1,pad(1)) true(1,center(1))], ...
        [false(1,pad(2)) true(1,center(2))]);

end
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be much more concise. I hope it's what you're looking for:

```
function I = normxcorr2e(template,im,shape)

  args={'full','same','valid'};
  cropSize=(find(strcmp(shape,args))-1)*size(template);
  crop=@(x,r) x(1+floor(r(1)/2):end-ceil(r(1)/2),1+floor(r(2)/2):end-ceil(r(2)/2))
  I=crop(normxcorr2(template,im),cropSize);
```

Comment: Thank you, your version and all others are good. Thus they were upvoted by me. I had a tough choice here.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much elegance here - you run the correlation, then you remove what you can't use. But it works.

```
function I = normxcorr2e(template,im,shape)

%# perform cross correlation with automated zero-padding
I = normxcorr2(template,im);

switch shape
    case 'same'

        %# if we were guaranteed to have odd-sized templates only
        %# we would only need padLow
        templateSize = size(template);
        padLow = floor(templateSize/2);
        padHigh = templateSize - padLow - 1;

        I = I( (1+padLow(1)):(end-padHigh(1)), (1+padLow(2)):(end-padHigh(2)) );

    case 'full'
        %Do nothing
    case 'valid'
        %# with even size, we need to remove the larger of the two pad sizes
        %# i.e. padLow, on all sides
        templateSize = size(template);
        padLow = templateSize/2;

        I = I( (2*padLow(1)):(end-2*padLow(1)+1), (2*padLow(2)):(end-2*padLow(2)+1) );
    otherwise
        throw(Mexception('normxcorr2e:BadInput','shape %s is not recognized',shape));
end
```

Comment: Thank you, your version and all others are good. Thus they were upvoted by me. I had a tough choice here.