# How to do the image matching?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have cropped out individual image of the objects as shown below and require to do a template matching. How can I apply the template matching method to my current coding? thanks

Processed Image:

http://i40.tinypic.com/2egh06o.jpg

Template:

http://i43.tinypic.com/531pvs.jpg

```
  im=imread('bus70.jpg');
  im=rgb2gray(im); % convert to gray scale
  im=im>graythresh(im)*255; % covert to binary
  siz=size(im); % image dimensions
  L=bwlabel(im,8); % Label the disconnected foreground regions (using 8 conned neighbourhood)
  % Get the bounding box around each object
  bb=regionprops(L,'BoundingBox');
  % Crop the individual objects and store them in a cell
  n=max(L(:)); % number of objects
  ObjCell=cell(n,1);
  for i=1:n
        % Get the bb of the i-th object and offest by 2 pixels in all
        % directions
        bb_i=ceil(bb(i).BoundingBox);
        idx_x=[bb_i(1)-2 bb_i(1)+bb_i(3)+2]; %  bb_i(1) read from 1st location
        idx_y=[bb_i(2)-2 bb_i(2)+bb_i(4)+2];
        if idx_x(1)<1, idx_x(1)=1; end
        if idx_y(1)<1, idx_y(1)=1; end
        if idx_x(2)>siz(2), idx_x(2)=siz(2); end
        if idx_y(2)>siz(1), idx_y(2)=siz(1); end
        % Crop the object and write to ObjCell
        im=L==i;
        ObjCell{i}=im(idx_y(1):idx_y(2),idx_x(1):idx_x(2));
  end
  % Visualize the individual objects
  figure
  for i=1:n
      subplot(1,n,i)

      imshow(ObjCell{i})
  end
  clear im L bb n i bb_i idx_x idx_y siz
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Run normalized cross correlation - `normxcorr2`
2. Find a peak (maximal value) in the result.
3. This is the location of the template. (Center)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145107/an-elegant-way-to-get-the-output-of-normxcorr2-in-a-manner-similar-to-conv2) might interest you as well.

Comment: how can i implement this in the coding?