# Linear convolution and cross-correlation of two vectors in Matlab using fft and same length output

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, convolution, cross-correlation

I'm implementing an algorithm where I need to compute the linear convolution and cross-correlation between two 1D vectors `a` and `b` using the FFT.  If the length of `a` is `m` and the length of `b` is `n`, then the total length of the resulting convolution will be `m + n - 1`.

However, the algorithm requires the output of the convolution to be the same length as the inputs.  Since `m = n`, the input vectors are the same length.

In Matlab, given that both vectors have been zero-padded to length `m + n - 1`, the convolution is computed as:

`ifft(fft(a).*fft(b))`

Alternately, the cross-correlation between the two vectors is computed as:

`fftshift(ifft(fft(a).*conj(fft(b))))`

The output is of length `m + n - 1`.  I need to zero-pad the vectors to ensure that circular convolution does not occur when using the FFT.

However, I would like the output length to be the same as the length of the inputs.  An associated question ([also on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253984/linear-convolution-of-two-images-in-matlab-using-fft2)) shows how the correlation of two images can be trimmed.

How do I trim the 1D output vector so that it is the same length as the input vectors?

Comment: (Might be helpful) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145107/an-elegant-way-to-get-the-output-of-normxcorr2-in-a-manner-similar-to-conv2

Comment: @Andrey: That was an interesting question, Andrey; thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB, `conv(a, b, 'same')` returns the central part of the convolution that is the same size as a. For cross correlation, you can use `xcorr`, which will give you the cross correlation result. I guess you need to crop the result by yourself to get the same size as input.

Comment: Thanks, chaohuang.  How does `conv(a, b, 'same')` return the central part of the convolution?  Which indices are used?  In addition, using `xcorr`, how would I appropriately crop the result?  Would this be the same central part of the response?

Comment: You can use help to see how to use `conv` or do some simple tests. Since there is no rule for cropping the convolution/correlation results, choosing the central parts is just one way to do it. You can choose whatever is most suitable for you.

Comment: Rather than using the `conv` function, I would like to do the convolution using the FFT. How does `conv` internally crop the result?  Is there maybe a reference book/paper showing how the cropping is done, even if there is no set rule?

Comment: It is probably best in this situation to use `conv(a, b, 'same')`

Answer (score 0):

there are formulas:

```
c = a conv b;
```

where, a, b and c are in time domain; After trans to frequency domain, the formula change to

```
C = A * B;
```

where, A, B and C are fft result of a, b, and c respectively, and all of them are in frequency domain; so c = ifft(C);

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification