# Normalized Cross correlation

Tags: correlation

Is there a neat a fast way of computing the normalised *cross correlation* of two signals in **MATLAB**?

My two signals `X` and `Y`
when I tried `C = normxcorr2(X,Y)` and plotted `C` my results did not look as I would expect

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: There is not enough information for the answer. You can look http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/normxcorr2.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145107/an-elegant-way-to-get-the-output-of-normxcorr2-in-a-manner-similar-to-conv2 . Maybe there is an answer for you question.